# converting 3-d text into 2-d file text

Tags: text, 3d, 2d, text-files

I am having a 512*512 types of file its a x*y type of file . now we are having 512 files of this type . these 512 files are like the z-axis if we have 100 files of this type then our total vertices are 512*512*100 , in this way I have to read a file is there any algorithm to read files arranged this type and putting into a single 2-d text file.

2-d text file will be like this
000 001 010 011 100 101 110 111 ,in this way we go on printing from the 3-d text file into a single 2-d text file

Is there any way to do that if anyone know please let me know that. any tutorial or any code

Sudhanshu

p.s : if you need any other information about my question you tell me.

Comment: What do you mean by a "type of file"?  A file that stores a 2-dimensional table?  Are you trying to merge files, or split them?

Comment: Can you give an example of the file's contents?

Comment: @bdares i mean its a text file which contains 2-d table with z=0 in first file then z=1 in second and going on like this . i want to merge these files into a single file in a way i above told you.

Comment: @WTP how can I give you an example. its just a file of which x=512 y=512 and z=0 and i am having 512 files like this we take another file for which x =512 y= 512 but z=1 so in this way no. are arranged now  i want to get all these numbers into a single text file like i explained above

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I'm going to parse it this way:

- You have some files of Type XY:

  - Each one has a 512*512 table.
  - You have Z of these files.
- You want to turn it into a new type of file, with a 512*512*512 table.

I'll assume that:

- You know how to perform basic file I/O.
- You know how to parse your existing file (it has a known delimiter for row/column).

It's surprisingly easy: concatenate the files.  You know the length, so you know that every 2^18 entries (or 2^9 rows) represents a X-Y plane at an integer Z-location.

If you're worried about the size changing, then go ahead and choose a new delimiter to represent a new Z-index.

Comment: 0.8 0.2 0.3 0.23 0.12 0.32 0.14 0.51 now in my code for ist vertex 000 of cube value is 0.8 . for 001 value is 0.2 for 010 vertex value is 0.3 in this way 8 vertices of cube takes 8 values abd they go on till you have values in text file and completing cubes containg values . now i have downloaded text files containing values but its arranged in the way you already understand . now I want to know how to change .